# Python, how to merge three dictionary in one filtering for key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

I have the following dictionaries:

```
personale_dip={'a': [550.0], 'b': [157.65]}
personale_dip_costo={'a': [1.0], 'b': [150.0]}
personale_result={'a': 550.0, 'b': 23648.64}
```

`Personale_result` has been obtained with the following code:

```
personale_result={k : v[0] * personale_dip_costo[k][0] for k, v in personale_dip.items() if k in personale_dip_costo}
```

I want to create a new variable, called `final_value` that, that for each key (matching them across dictionary) summarize all three dictionary giving me the following result:

```
final_value={'a': [550.0, 1.0, 550.0],   'b': [157.65, 150.0, 23648.64]}
```

How should I do it? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I have tried the following code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

personale_dip = {'a': [550.0], 'b': [157.65]}
personale_dip_costo = {'a': [1.0], 'b': [150.0]}
personale_result = {'a': 550.0, 'b': 23648.64}

data = defaultdict(list)

for d in [personale_dip, personale_dip_costo, personale_result]:
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, list):
            data[k].extend(v)
        else:
            data[k].append(v)
```

but the result is

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': [550.0, 1.0, 550.0], 'b': [157.65, 150.0, 23648.64]})
```

If I want to obtain only

```
{'a': [550.0, 1.0, 550.0], 'b': [157.65, 150.0, 23648.64]}
```

How could I get it?

Comment: `what_you_want = dict(data.items())` ? A defaultdict is just a dict with sugar on top ... why not keep the defaultdict?

Comment: Hey, I have edited my answer, can you please check, if that is of any use to you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you where on the right track. Personally I would simply merge them:

```python
final_value = {}
for key in personale_result:
    final_value[key] = (personale_dip[key][0], personale_dip_costo[key][0], personal_result[key])
```

With your input this will give you:

```
>>> final_result
{'a': [550.0, 1.0, 550.0], 'b': [157.65, 150.0, 23647.5]}
```

Now personale_dip and personale_dip_costo are of type {string, list}.
Currently your personale_result will simply ignore other values in that list, as will final_result.

Answer (score 1):

**ANSWER 2.0**

```
personale_dip={'a': [550.0], 'b': [157.65]}
personale_dip_costo={'a': [1.0], 'b': [150.0]}
personale_result={'a': 550.0, 'b': 23648.64}

final_value = {}

for dictionary in [personale_dip, personale_dip_costo, personale_result]:
    for k,v in dictionary.items():
        # if the key is there, then 
        # check whether it a list or a normal string
        # if list add it like [] + []
        # if not then add it like [] + [v]
        if k in final_value:
            if isinstance(v, type([])): final_value[k] += v
            else: final_value[k] += [v]
        else:
            if isinstance(v, type([])): final_value[k] = v
            else: final_value[k] = [v]
print(final_value)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
>>> {'a': [550.0, 1.0, 550.0], 'b': [157.65, 150.0, 23648.64]}
```

This is edited, and gives you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
personale_dip = {'a': [550.0], 'b': [157.65]}
personale_dip_costo = {'a': [1.0], 'b': [150.0]}
personale_result = dict()
for key_pd in personale_dip:
    if key_pd in personale_dip_costo.keys():
        personale_result[key_pd] = [personale_dip[key_pd][0], personale_dip_costo[key_pd][0], personale_dip[key_pd][0]*personale_dip_costo[key_pd][0]]
```

This code should work considering the list inside the dict contains only 1 element. This will work even if personale_dip has more elements or vice versa.